# Remove padding in A tag

Tags: html, css, padding

Why am I getting this strange padding, and how can I remove it?

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black;">
<a href="?lang=ru" ><img  src="http://top-5ive.net/images/flags/ru.png" alt=""></a>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uE9F6/1/

Comment: What strange padding? Could you show us? And show us the CSS/HTML that seems related?

Comment: Are you talking about an anchor tag? What padding are you talking about? More detail man

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm sorry, code didn't show, I've edited post.

Comment: @PRPGFerret I'm sorry, code didn't show, I've edited post.

Comment: Do you mean the space character before and after the tag?

Comment: The padding property is set to 0, what strange padding are you seeing?

Comment: Do you mean the line height setting the height of the line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `line-height` is bigger than the image of the flag.  Specify `line-height:11px;`. [See this jsFiddle for more help](http://jsfiddle.net/dvfz2/).

For more information on this, see the [W3C's information on the height of a line](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/#the-height-of-lines).